# Am I using version JDK 17 or version openJDK 1.8?

Tags: java, windows, visual-studio

recently I tried to update my JDK and when I checked what version do I use then I realised that I'm running on openJDK v.1.8 while I should be using JDK 17.0.4

When I typed "where java" in CMD, then I found I have 3 installations of JDK.
see attached picture -> figure no.1.

Now I am confused.

The cmd path shows something called Eclipse Foundation folder, but I have never ever used Eclipse IDE on this pc. I think this folder is connected with the Visual Studio IDE (VS).

After I uninstalled Visual Studio 2019, because I thought that one was responsible for the openJDK 1.8 - the Eclipse Foundation folder really dissapeared.

screenshot from cmd before uninstallation VS, figure no.1 ->

[image: figure no.1]

screenshot from cmd after uninstallation of VS, figure no.2 ->

[image: figure no.2]

So my question is:
**Which version of java was used before I uninstalled the VS?
Was it JDK 17 or version openJDK 1.8 ?**

I solved the problem by uninstalling the VS. And the cmd clearly stated that I was using *openJDK v.1.8* instead of *JDK 17.0.4*

I have now another question:
Q>
**Is there a way how to instal Visual Studio without messing my JDK?**

Comment: just a thought: does Visual Studio use the Eclipse JDT language server for autocompletion, rrefactoring etc.? if so, it is possible that it installs the Temurin JDK to run the LS.

Comment: You can make sure that you use the correct version of Java by placing its directory before the Eclipse JDK in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for both answers, I will try it out later when i will need VS again. I will check if I am able to change my desired JDK PATH in the environmental variables.